# Angular2 how to check if clicked on body outside

Tags: jquery, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services

Is there a way to check if body is clicked in Angular2 as in jQuery:

```
$('body').click(function() {
       alert("Hello");
    });
```

I want to do same in Angular2 how can I do that ?

Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing something like this : in the template of of your root selector usually named **app.component.html**, create a div that will encapsulate your entire page and add a click event to this div.

```
<div id="page-body-wrapper" (click)="clickTrigger($event)">
   ... all app content loaded here...
</div>
```

In your **app.component.ts**

```
clickTrigger(event: MouseEvent){
    //event.preventDefault();
     //console.log('something happend');
       // Do what you want on click
  }
}
```